# can sklearn.dbscan or sklearn.kmeans be used for more than 2 dimension?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining

In my recent project, someone tried to cluster a multi-dimentional data set with sklearn.dbscan. But I am highly doubtful with this approach.

How can we know the eps and min_samples? I mean there is no way you can observe the size of the cluster, cause the data set is in a multi-dimensional space.

as I can see the approachs are already in the wiki page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_high-dimensional_data

These approaches are what I am looking for right?

I am not sure if I got this problem correctly. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how many dimensions we are talking about. I'd say if it's less than ~10 you can try to directly use DBSCAN. Otherwise some kind of dimensionality reduction is likely to give you better results.

Anyway the concrete approach will depend on the specific problem.

Comment: hi. I'd say the dimention is about 10. But I still have no idea, how can we set the esp for multi-dimensional data set? I mean, even we set it we cannot really observe if the result is correct.

Comment: Evaluating a clustering (unsupervised) result is a challenge on its own. If the data is not <4 dimensions you hardly can use a visual approach. The right method again depends on the problem: do you know the number of clusters in advance? What do you know about the problem domain? eps and min_samples will be set accordingly. For example here you find some clues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN#Parameter_estimation

Comment: HI Marco, before the approach I do not know how many clusters there might be, neither do I know the density etc...... So in my case directly use sklearn.dbscan or kmeans is a wrong idea, right?

Comment: Aside from the raw data, you must know something about your problem. For example what a datapoint represents. Otherwise you are blind.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to only use this for 2d data.

Both work *very* well on 3d data.

I'd say dimensions up to 50 are usually just fine. Afterwards it does eventually get tricky, depending on your data. Color histograms with hundreds of dimensions can still work okay, for example. So can text because it's intrinsic dimensionality usually is much less, but I don't think DBSCAN is a good choice for text.
Spherical k-means even is a standard technique for clustering text with "formally" 50000+ dimensions...

Low dimensionality is important for *grid-based* approaches, though. But neither DBSCAN not k-means is grid-based. I would rather not use DenClue though.

Comment: hi. thnx for the comment. But how can I observe if the cluster is good or how can I evaluate the result? Cause basically there is no way to observe the result right?

Comment: I mean how can I observe the result in a 50-dimensional space?

Comment: Depends on your data. Maybe you have decided a way to make your data interpretable. Supposedly it's not 50d random, but has some meaning.